# Access console logs from VS Code extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm working on a VS code extension which needs to access `console.log()` output, written into the user's active terminal.

I'm aware of the `vscode.window.activeTerminal` API which returns a `Terminal`. However, according to the [docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#Terminal) I can only `sendText()` to the terminal.

Is it possible to read the terminal's content from within my extension?

Answer (score 1):

It cannot do in stable version of VSCode. Try `window.onDidWriteTerminalData` API only in Insider version.

For your information, there are several options, not official supported by VSCode.

1. Use node-pty to create and manage the process and then hook it up using `ExtensionTerminalOptions`.
2. Create a process/script that wraps the terminal shell.

reference:

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/83224

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/commit/dc6b475be75999e78233f9f6951ef66f18f768ea#r53974957